# How to substitute particular values of POST query for InvokeHTTP?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the following sequence of processors:

[image]

I create the body of POST query using `ReplaceText` processor. This processor is linked to `InvokeHTTP`.
The replacement value in `ReplaceText` is:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"Field1": ""}},
        {"term": {"Field2": ""}},
        {"term": {"Field3": ""}},
        {"term": {"Field4": ""}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "ranges": [
                { 
                   "from": "2017-02-17T16:00:00Z||-1H/H",
                   "to": "2017-02-17T16:00:00Z||/H" 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Before executing the query in `InvokeHTTP`, I need to replace the values of `Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3` and `Field4` according to the values of the actual fields of the input FlowFile (the output of `UpdateAttribute`).

For example, in the input FlowFile I have `Field1` equal to `ABC`, so in my POST query `Field1` should be equal to `ABC` instead of an empty string.

What is the better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [NiFi Expression Language](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) in your ReplaceText. Assuming you have 4 attributes field.1 thru field.4, you can replace the entire text with the following:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"Field1": "${field.1}"}},
        {"term": {"Field2": "${field.2}"}},
        {"term": {"Field3": "${field.3}"}},
        {"term": {"Field4": "${field.4}"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "ranges": [
                { 
                   "from": "2017-02-17T16:00:00Z||-1H/H",
                   "to": "2017-02-17T16:00:00Z||/H" 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand one thing. Let's say I have `ListenHTTP` that outputs FlowFile with this content `{"field1":"AAA","field2":"BBB","field3":"CCC"}`. Right after `ListenHTTP` I added `UpdateAttribute` and created the properties `field1`, `field2` and `field3` with values `${field1}`, `${field2}` and `${field3}`, accordingly. But when I set `{"term": {"Field1": "${field1}"}},` in my POST query as you suggested, all fields are empty. What do I miss?

Comment: Your fields are in your content, not in attributes, so you can't refer to them using Expression Language. To get them out of the JSON and into attributes, use EvaluateJsonPath. You'd have a dynamic property called "field1" whose value is the JSON Path "/field1", and the same goes for the rest of the fields. EvaluateJSONPath will replace UpdateAttribute in your flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReplaceText` to use a regular expression to match the field definitions and replace them with the value of the attributes. Unfortunately it would be a little tricky to parameterize the [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) to repeat with every number, so it's better to define them explicitly:

- *Search value*: `"Field1"\: ""`
- *Replacement value*: `"Field1": "${field1}"`